# Array in structure

Tags: c

I'm new to C. Below are codes written in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[256];
    int age;
    int sex;
} People;

void InputPeople(People *data);
void ShowPeople(People data);

int main(void)
{
    int i,count,datasize;
    People *data;

    datasize = 10;
    data = (People*)malloc(sizeof(People) * datasize);

    count = 0;
    while (1) {
        InputPeople(&data[count]);
        if (data[count].age == -1) break;
        count++;

        if (count >= datasize) {
            datasize += 10;
            data = (People*)realloc(data,sizeof(People) * datasize);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0;i < count;i++) {
        ShowPeople(data[i]);
    }

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why it is possible to write like "data[count]". I've learned Structure and Array. I would appreciate if somebody could explain to me.

Comment: In many ways pointers and arrays are treated as the same thing. One example being that you can use array-indexing for both.

Comment: Also, it seems you really should [find a good beginners book about C to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), instead of asking extremely basic questions.

Comment: Also you should think about what part of your code example is relevant to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I'm currently learning in the internet. I will buy a good beginners book about C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`People` is your struct.

You declare a `People` pointer, which then points to the memory that you dynamically allocated with `malloc()`. How big is that memory chunk you allocated? `datasize` * size of the struct, i.e. 10 structs, since `datasize = 10`.

That means that `data` now points to a 1D array, thus you can index it like `data[0]` to get the first element (struct). `count` is a counter, which can be 0 as well.

You can think it like you had done `People data[10];`, which statically declares an array of 10 structs `People`, although it's not the same, since in your code the memory is dynamically allocated.

---

BTW, [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No.

Also, I would suggest you to [read a C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thank you for much for your quick reply, gsamars. I will learn basics more.